# Should one use redis to generate auto incrementing values?

Tags: redis

I am designing an application that uses MongoDB for storage. As you probably know the ObjectId datatype that mongo provides is a 12 byte hexadecimal. I would like to show my users a more user friendly id instead.

I looked into several options like PHP's uniqid() and several variations thereof but I don't trust them because of the collisions the randomness entails (see [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table)).

Redis looks really attractive to me for this kind of operation (see [INCR](http://redis.io/commands/incr)). This requires the web application to call redis every time it needs to create new record. I will only need about 15-20 counters inside redis which will have a tiny footprint so replication will never become an issue. Also the app can connect to it using a socket to avoid the tcp overhead.

Am I thinking about it the wrong way? Is there something else I should consider?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What happens if redis gets flushed?  You should at least have a backup plan for re-populating it.

Answer (score 5):

"Should" is such a strong word...

I would say, if you keep redis around anyway, you could use it for counters. You will probably find it useful for other things, too. But if you think about installing and maintaining redis just for atomic counters, that seems a little bit over the top.

Apparently, Mongo can also do atomic counters, from [How to make an auto incrementing field](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field):

With a "counter model" such as:

```
db.counters.insert({_id: "userId", next: 0});

var userCounter = db.findAndModify({
  query: {_id: "userId"},
  update: {$inc: {next: 1}}
});
```

You can now use `userCounter.next` as your id.

With that said, if I were you I think I'd go for keeping the `_id` as a Mongo `ObjectID` and keep a separate property for the auto-incremented id.

Comment: Linus don't you think that redis will give a much higher throughput as compared to mongo when it comes to auto increment ids. The way Alex suggested does help in preventing auto increment id generation being a bottleneck for document insertion in mongo at scale. Probably that's the reason why mongo doesn't use auto increment ids in the first place. Thoughts?